# ExtJS/HTML -- tooltip not hiding on mouseout

Tags: html, extjs

I have added an icon to a fieldLabel. On mouseover of the icon I show a tooltip. But on mouseout the tooltip isn't hidden/destroyed.

Is my target correct? I also tried `target:a.target,`and `target:a.target.id`

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1a86) is the fiddle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this
                                                 var shows = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                  fields: ['id','show'],
                                                data: [
                                                    {id: 0, show: 'Battlestar Galactica'},
                                                    {id: 1, show: 'Doctor Who'},
                                                    {id: 2, show: 'Farscape'},
                                                    {id: 3, show: 'Firefly'},
                                                    {id: 4, show: 'Star Trek'},
                                                    {id: 5, show: 'Star Wars: Christmas Special'}
                                                ]
                                             });

```
                                        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                                            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                                            title: 'Sci-Fi Television',
                                            height: 200,
                                            width: 500,
                                            items: [{
                                                xtype: 'tagfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Select a Show'+'<img id="test"                         src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/glyphpack/85/info-alt-128.png" style="height:15px;width:15px;">',
                                                store: shows,
                                                listeners: {
                                                    afterrender: function(){
                                                        var a = Ext.getElementById("test");
                                                        var tip = Ext.create("Ext.tip.ToolTip", {

                                                  header:false,  
                                                  autoScroll:true,
                                                  autoHide:true,
                                                  autoDestroy:true,
                                                  closeAction:"hide",
                                                  target:a,
                                                  html:[            
                                                   '<div class="hopscotch-bubble-container" padding: 5px;">',          
                                                    '<div class="hopscotch-content">',
                                                      '<h3 class="hopscotch-title"><b>Instructions</b></h3>',
                                                      '<div class="hopscotch-content">field instructions here</div>',
                                                    '</div>',                    
                                                   '</div>',
                                                  '<div class="hopscotch-bubble-arrow-container left">',
                                                    '<div class="hopscotch-bubble-arrow-border"></div>',
                                                    '<div class="hopscotch-bubble-arrow"></div>',
                                                  '</div>'
                                                  ],          
                                                  width:"auto",
                                                  height:"auto"          
                                                });

                                                tip.showAt(a.target.x,a.target.y);

                                                    }  
                                                },
                                                displayField: 'show',
                                                valueField: 'id',
                                                queryMode: 'local',
                                                filterPickList: true
                                            }]
                                        });
```